# How to add .xcworkspace to .xcodeprodj

Tags: ios, xcode

I write SDK and use cocoapods for adding thirdpart code - together it is .xcworkspace.
For debug purpose I write simple application (it is .xcodeprodj) and want to connect my SDK workspace. But it's not connected as .xcodeprodj to .xcodeprodj.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A workspace is a container that can contain multiple project. A workspace contains projects, but not the other way around.

Comment: And what you do, if you want develop a project from another debug-project?